# Typo3 - Extbase Bootstrap->run ignores content element's record storage page

Tags: ajax, typo3, storage, record, extbase

I have an extension which adds a custom content element called "Products".
I'm trying to make an ajax pagination. When I try to get the products list with styles.content.get, the products are rendered correctly, but when I'm using the extbase way, I get no products.

The custom page type:

```
ajaxProductList = PAGE
ajaxProductList {
    typeNum = 6

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/html
    }

    # WORKING
    10 < styles.content.get
    10.where = CType='products_main'

    # NOT WORKING
    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = Products
        pluginName = Main
        vendorName = Vendor
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

**EDIT:**

Adding the storagePid manually under vendorName fixes the issue, but is there any way this could be considered automatically?

```
persistence.storagePid = 116
```

Comment: You miss the ``flexform`` configuration in the ``10 = USER`` example.

Comment: Hi pgampe, there is no flexform involved.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are wrong. ``TYPO3 CMS`` does not magically add settings ;)